# Powershell get-content split columns into duple

Tags: powershell, foreach, skype

I need to register several users in SFB, and I need to register the user and the phone extension for their respective user, within a TXT I have two columns the user and extension separated by " ; ", My doubt is, how to separate columns within the foreach command? and will the user name and phone extension be added to the code correctly?

---

sampleData.txt

user                 |         extension

```
myuser1@mycompany.com ; 3331 <br/>
myuser2@mycompany.com ; 3332 <br/>
myuser2@mycompany.com ; 3334 <br/>
```

*---------------------------------------------------------------*

```
$user = Get-Content C:\temp\skypeproject\sampleData.txt

foreach ($users in $user) {  Set-CsUser –Identity $users –EnterpriseVoiceEnabled $true
<br/> <br/>
  –OnPremLineURI tel:+3333333$extension  <br/>  <br/>
  Set-CsUserPstnSettings –Identity "$users" –HybridPSTNSite ACCESSPOOL <br/> <br/>
  Grant-CsTenantDialPlan –Identity "$users" –PolicyName Company <br/> <br/>

}
```

Comment: Consider using `Import-CSV`, it's got `-Delimiter` switch.

Answer (score 1):

As [vonPryz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503046/vonpryz) suggested use `Import-CSV` to get the data from the file. You can include the header of the columns in the file delimited the same way as the rest of the data or add the header later with the cmdlet:

**No header:**

```
$path = "path\to\sampleData.txt"
$csv = Import-Csv -Path $path -Delimiter ";" -Header "user","extension"
foreach ($row in $csv) {  
    $users = $row.user 
    $extension = $row.extension
    Set-CsUser –Identity $users –EnterpriseVoiceEnabled $true –OnPremLineURI tel:+3333333$extension
    Set-CsUserPstnSettings –Identity $users –HybridPSTNSite ACCESSPOOL
    Grant-CsTenantDialPlan –Identity $users –PolicyName Company
}
```

**header in file:**

```
$path = "path\to\sampleData.txt"
$user = Import-Csv -Path $path -Delimiter ";"
foreach ($row in $csv) {  
    $users = $row.user 
    $extension = $row.extension
    Set-CsUser –Identity $users –EnterpriseVoiceEnabled $true –OnPremLineURI tel:+3333333$extension
    Set-CsUserPstnSettings –Identity $users –HybridPSTNSite ACCESSPOOL
    Grant-CsTenantDialPlan –Identity $users –PolicyName Company
}
```

file:

```
user;extension
myuser1@mycompany.com;3331
myuser2@mycompany.com;3332
myuser2@mycompany.com;3334
```

Note that whitespaces in the file are included! Either remove them from you file or you need to `trim` the output:

```
$users = $row.user.trim()
$extension = $row.extension.trim()
```

Comment: Hi vonPryz thanks for your reply, I have a doubt. You used Import-CSV. so my date file must be CSV? or can i use TXT? I ran your code suggestion but nothing happened.
Thank you

Comment: `Import-CSV` takes every text file and tries to handle it as a CSV-file. A [CSV-file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is a kind of a table that uses commas or other characters as delimiters. So it should work anyway. What is the output when you type `$csv` after `$csv = Import-Csv ...` is executed?